# are there conflicts between use-package and a package's autoloads?

Tags: use-package, autoload

Do I have to worry about a package's built-in autoloads somehow conflicting with those implicitly defined by use-package? For example if I do `:commands some-cmd` but the package already had an autoload created for `some-cmd`, will there be any problems?

Comment: I think no, since [#177](https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package/issues/177) is solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you should run into any problems.  I use `:bind` for commands that are already autoloaded (note that `:bind` implicitly generates autoloads, in the same way as `:commands`), and haven't run into any problems.  And if you're using `:commands` and not `:bind` and you run into problems because of this, you should be able to solve them just by dropping the `:commands` directive.

User npostavs linked to [this github issue](https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package/issues/177) in a comment, which suggests that there was previously a problem with `:commands` clobbering pre-existing autoloads, but this has since been fixed.  Reading through it might be helpful if problems do arise.